# large template class boilerplate code

Tags: c++, templates, dry

I have large template class with several methods etc.

Most of the methods do not use template parameter - Only few methods uses template parameter.

Is there a way to minimize boilerplate code?

```
template <class T>
class Something{
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
};

template <class T>
void Something<T>::method1(){
    T::use();
}

template <class T>
void Something<T>::method2(){
    // do not use T at all, does not call method1()
}

template <class T>
void Something<T>::method3(){
    // do not use T at all, does not call method1()
}
```

Any way I can avoid `template <class T>` (in my real code template definition is way much bigger) ?

Comment: you can put the definitions right after the declaration. Anyway templates go in header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the non-template dependent methods in a base class.

```
class SomethingBase
{
protected:
  void method2();
  void method3();
};

template<typename T>
class Something
: SomethingBase
{
public:
  void method1();
  using SomethingBase::method2;
  using SomethingBase::method3;
};
```

This does not change the functionality of the class, but is a bit more cumbersome than Neil Kirk's approach, which should be preferred if applicable.

If, as here, the only functionality of the base is to provide less specialised functionality for derived classes, all its members, including the constructors, should be `protected`.

Comment: While this is common suggestion, it has some drawbacks. You introduce is-a relationship to something which is not naturally is-a, and what was only itroduced to save on typing. Private iheritance is much better here.

Comment: @SergeyA The base is not *only introduced to save typing*. It allows those `method2()` and `method3()` to be defined in a source file and thus reduces compilation. Moreover, in case of specialisation of the derived classes, it avoids re-defining (copy & paste) similar or even identical methods.

Comment: Fair enough, not only to save on typing (I saved on typing here). It still had nothing to do with IS-A relationship reflected in public inheritance, but private inheritance with protected members of base class is the solution, as I mentioned.

Comment: honestly, i did accept this answer, because it is doing whatever I asked. However, when I tryed to separated the class into base + templated, it does look very bad and non intuitive. So probably I will make it with the boilerplate code.

Comment: @Nick *it does look very bad and non intuitive* is obviously subjective. If your non-template methods are trivial, then the 'boiler-plate code' is certainly viable, but if they are heavy functions that are best pre-compiled, separating them out in a base class is certainly much better.

Comment: @Walter sure. but i still learning C++11 and I do not pay attention to  compile time yet. Also I explicitly instantiating the templates at the end.

Comment: @Nick 1) You should pay attention to what is inlined and/or cannot be pre-compiled, for you want to avoid bloated header files. 2) You can only explicitly instantiate your template once you know the template parameters, and for most useful templates you don't -- think about `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 1):

If only `method1` uses the template parameter, only that function needs to be templated.

```
class Something
{
    template<class T>
    void method1()
    {
        T::use();
    }

    void method2();
    void method3();
};
```

Note that this slightly changes the functionality of the class. It's now possible for an instance to be called with a variety of types on its `method1` whereas before only 1 type was possible and had to be decided up front.

Comment: I cannot move template to the method1(). I thought something with inheritance, but is ugly anyway.

Comment: @Nick You should put these restrictions in your question.